# Do you have to include all leading lags in a regression model?

Tags: regression, time-series, lags

Let's say you have a regression model in the below form:

y = x(t) + x(t-1) + x(t-2) + c

If x(t-2) is a significant predictor for y, but the x and x(t-1) variables are not, can you drop those variables? So the new model would be:

y = x(t-2) + c

I always thought you should keep the leading lags in the model, but I was doing some research and now I'm thinking that might not be the case. For context, I am trying to model economic data using macroeconomic variables such as unemployment, GDP, etc.

Comment: At first glance, your question sounds a lot like leaving a main effect in the regression if only an interaction is significant. In this case you generally leave the main effect in. On the other hand, a better (?) analogy might be seasonality. It doesn't strike me as unusual to include the 12-month lag (yearly seasonality) but not each of the other 11-month lags.

I'm don't know enough to make this an answer, though.

Comment: I think some very similar questions have been asked before, so this might be a duplicate.